# libjpeg.so.62 Not Found by Starcraft 2 WINE causing a failure to load! (Patcher after install)

Tags: wine

libjpeg.so.62 Not Found by Starcraft 2 WINE causing a failure to load!

This is on the Patcher for starcraft 2 that is failing. Installed all the libjpeg packages and the 62 version and the dev's from the software center.

```
err:wincodecs:JpegDecoder_CreateInstance Failed reading JPEG because unable to find libjpeg.so.62
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: I have same problem, I'm on 12.04 64bit intel.

Comment: The problem is with the 64-bit library ..

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

sudo apt-get install libjpeg62

I found the solution here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1846079

Comment: If you're using a 32bit wine prefix you'll need to install the 32bit library `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386`